# How to set a little icon on files under windows?

Tags: c#, c++, winapi

i would to set dynamically a little icon on the files (maybe on folders too) that i lock with my app.

I saw it with google app for synchronize, a little "refresh icon" appears to symbolize they are in synchronization, and i want make the same thing with my app that lock temporarely files to prevent changement meanwhile it works on it.

- I Imagine it must use c++ api for Windows ?
- It needs to change all the icon or with windows 10 you can add by a layer another icon ?
- How to change dynamically an icon files ?

thanks.

Informations:

- Environnement: Windows10.
- Target: Files icon.
- Language: c#, maybe
  c++ api windows.

Comment: [How to Implement Icon Overlay Handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/how-to-implement-icon-overlay-handlers)

Comment: Due to the limit of [max 15 overlays](https://superuser.com/questions/1166577/why-does-windows-limit-icon-overlays-to-15) in Windows, the overlay handler solution isn't really practical, requiring your app to constantly "fight" with other apps for the spot in the overlay list. I suggest to abandon the idea entirely.

Comment: Thx for the informations Jonathan Potter i will read it, i didn't know the right terms.

RustyX i keep in mind your warning, i will test before.

Answer (score 0):

> You can assign icons to the members of the file type by implementing
>   an icon handler. An icon handler is a type of Shell extension handler
>   that allows you to dynamically assign icons to the members of a file
>   type.

Refer to "[How to Create Icon Handlers](http://How%20to%20Create%20Icon%20Handlers)".

Similar topic: "[How to create a IconHandler used by the shell in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16952684/how-to-create-a-iconhandler-used-by-the-shell-in-c)"